# Retrieving row count without using Count function

Tags: sql-server-2005, select, count

I wrote a query below which shoots me a syntax error why would it do so,

```
SELECT MAX('Row') FROM 

(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID DESC) 'Row' FROM USERS)
```

**Error Desc:**

```
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

I don't get it :(

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are actually three problems with the query.  The first is `Max('Row')` will return the string 'Row'. The second is your subquery needs an alias.

Try like this:

```
 SELECT MAX(Row) FROM 
 (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID DESC) Row FROM USERS) UserQuery
```

The third problem is that `count()` is a much better way as expertly described in [the answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/3853/1192) by gbn.

Note also that `ROW` is in the [Reserved Keywords List](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx), so that should be avoided as well.

Comment: Thank you so very much. using just Count(ColumnName) would not give the correct count if there were multiple same numbers. This worked out absolutely perfect! Thank you.

Comment: Count(*) is better

Comment: Are you talking about replacing --- MAX(Row) with --- Count(*)? I just ran a test and received the same results. Please let me know why Count(*) is the better choice.

Comment: I'm saying a simple  `select count(*) from <your table>` is the simplest and best approach.  This original question was an edge case.  Use * instead of a specific column name.  See answer from gbn below.  This was one selected as answer for the edge case only.

Comment: Thank you, Thomas. Never thought of using (*) before in a count. I had seen it around but never thought about it. As long as you have the "where column=1" you get your count. Thank you.

Answer (score 21):

- If you want to get the exact count of rows in an efficient manner, then `COUNT(*)` is it. The [ANSI standard](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) (look for "`Scalar expressions   125`") states that `COUNT(*)` give the row count of a table: it is intended to be optimised from the start.

> If COUNT(*) is specified, then the result is the cardinality of T.

- A ROW_NUMBER() function isn't a practical option: it isn't a counting function (it's  "ROW_NUMBER") and it will run badly as you add rows: a few 1000 will show how bad this it
- SUM(1) may be optimised to COUNT(*) internally but I'd never use it
- @@ROWCOUNT will require all rows to be returned by the first SELECT, which is a huge unnecessary overhead.

If you can live with approximate for SQL Server then use sys.dm_db_partition_stats. Marian's answer is out of date now since SQL Server 2005 added dmvs

```
SELECT
   Total_Rows= SUM(st.row_count)
FROM
   sys.dm_db_partition_stats st
WHERE
    object_name(object_id) = 'Mytable' AND (index_id < 2)
```

See this on SO too for some more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069237/fastest-way-to-count-exact-number-of-rows-in-a-very-large-table/6069288#6069288

In summary, there is exactly *one* useful way of getting the number of rows in a table. COUNT(*)

Answer (score 6):

There's another variant, without scanning the table, using system tables:

```
Select si.RowCnt
from sys.objects so join sysindexes si on si.id = so.object_id
where so.type_desc = 'USER_TABLE'
and si.indid in (0,1) -- heap or clustered index
and so.Name in ('Users')
```

Compare plans, durations, time.. You'll see it's a faster variant.

Comment: Presumably this does not give an *exact* count though?

Answer (score -1):

Change you query to :

```
SELECT MAX(A.Row) FROM 
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID DESC) as Row FROM Users) as A
```

Try this mate.

Answer (score -1):

select si.rowcnt from sysindexes si where si.indid in (0,1) and si.id=Object_ID('Users')

Answer (score -1):

Check This Simple Query :

```
select rows from sysindexes where Id = OBJECT_ID('TableName') and indid <2
```

Answer (score -2):

This is faster

```
SELECT SUM (row_count)
FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats
WHERE object_id=OBJECT_ID('Users')   
AND (index_id<2);
```